# Automatically add rows daily and append previous day's data

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a small database that gets data dumped into it manually every day that looks like this. Each day the data below will be dumped (just with updated date in column A)

[image: pic 1 - initial database dump]

On another sheet I am trying to create a daily snapshot of the total cash that is in the machines (E:E + F:F + G1) and the total volume (C:C) on a specific day. In this case it would be for 7/27/15. Hopefully looking something like this:

[image: pic 2 - sheet with formulas layered on database dump]

What I would like is for each day that I add in new data to the original sheet that the sheet with the formulas appends the previous date and adds in a row with todays formulas/data. Like this:

[image: pic 3]

Hopefully someone out there understands what I am trying to accomplish. I understand formulas quite well with sheets I just tried to word and present my problem as clearly as possible as no formulas that I've tried have worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Without a script

First, fill column A of the second sheet with

```
=IF(TODAY()-ROW()+2>=DATE(2015,1,1), TODAY()-ROW()+2, "")
```

where DATE(...) is the date that your records begin. This creates a reverse-chronological list of dates, beginning with today. It will be automatically updated as `TODAY()` changes. As any non-script solution, this approach is limited by the fact that formulas can not add rows to a sheet. So you should give the second sheet plenty of rows to begin with.

In column C, put formulas like

```
=IF(A2="", "", SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, "="&A2, Sheet1!C:C))
```

totaling the C amounts for a given date, if there is a date.

In column B, put something similar:

```
=IF(A2="", "",  SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, "="&A2, Sheet1!F:G) + VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:G, 7, FALSE))
```

where `VLOOKUP` takes one value from column G.

A disadvantage of the above is that the calculations will be slow because all the data on Sheet2 are recalculated  every day.

#### With a script

A script can use the same formulas as given above: no need to replicate the logic. Additional benefits:

- rows inserted automatically
- possible to freeze archived values in Sheet2, so that if someone goes back to fudge the books in Sheet1, the record in Sheet2 will stay.

Here is such a script:

```
function daily() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sh.insertRowAfter(1);
  sh.getRange("A2").setFormula('=A3+1');
  sh.getRange("B2").setFormula('=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, "="&A2, Sheet1!F:G) + VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:G, 7, FALSE)');
  sh.getRange("C2").setFormula('=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A, "="&A2, Sheet1!C:C)');
  var freeze = sh.getRange("A3:C3");
  freeze.copyTo(freeze,{contentsOnly:true});  
}
```

The code is mostly self-explanatory: a row is added and filled with formulas. The two lines with "freeze" are optional: they replace the formulas in yesterday's row with the calculated values. If you don't want this to happen, remove them.

Column A should be formatted as "date" so that it displays correctly. You will also need to put a date in A2 to get the process started; subsequent dates will appear automatically.

To have the script run daily, add a trigger from the Script Editor: it's under "Resources > Current project's triggers". You can pick the hour of day when the script should run.

Comment: Cant you make that work by using an ARRAYFORMULA or use QUERY to contruct the other sheet?

Comment: So I completely understand SUMIF(s) and I have those formulas down to add everything up correctly for a given day. The issue I'm having is that using something like ARRAYFORMULA does not populate the rest of the cells.   Also, I need a new row to be inserted automatically everyday with the same formulas and to have the previous days data/formulas pushed down to the row below. That way every single day the sheet gets updated automatically with new data and logs the old.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra This was a somewhat tentative answer, which succeeded at clarifying what needs to be done. In particular, newest data should go on top, which I suppose can still be done with some queries (rebuilding the second sheet every day), but probably easier with a script.

Comment: @CailenSullivan I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thank you for that! I'm close, but still not quite there. Would you be willing to help me out via direct contact (email, screenshare, etc)? Not sure if I can convey the issue I'm running into on this thread. Let me know if this is possible :)

Comment: @CailenSullivan Sorry, I don't offer personalized help.

Comment: @NormalHuman No problem. I actually figured it out thanks to your help with the script so thank you! One more question I have is with the trigger. Right now it is set up daily. However, is there a way to create a trigger so that the script is run ONLY when I insert new data in Sheet1 that has a different date in column A from the previous time I inserted data?????

Comment: If someone is wondering how to add time trigger in new editor its in the left menu under triggers -> add trigger -> select event source -> time driven